# How to prove that every tangent bundle of a surface has a locally trivialization?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ be a $C^\infty$ surface (manifold) of dimension $m$. The set $TM=\{
(x,v)\in\mathbb{R^n\times R^n} ; x\in M,v\in T_xM\}$ is called the tangent bundle of $M$. Define $\pi:TM\to M$ by $\pi(x,v)=x$. I want to show that for any $x\in M$, there is an open neighborhood $V\subset M$ of $x$ such that $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is diffeomorphic to $V\times\mathbb{R^n}$. There is a way to prove this using the submersion theorem? Because in fact $\pi$ is a submersion. How to find this diffeomorphism? I've tried only to prove this using the fact that $\pi$ is a submersion, but it was fruitless. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this not (almost) a direct consequence of the way you define the smooth structure on $TM$?

Comment: If I take the parametrization $\psi (u,v)=(\phi(u),\phi^\prime(u)v)=\left(\phi(u),\alpha_1(v)\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial u_1}(u)+\cdots+ \alpha_n(v)\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial u_n}(u)\right)$ it works?